# Reference for fast algorithm for bottleneck shortest paths

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms

I am looking for a good reference for bottleneck shortest paths.  Specifically, given vertices s and t in an undirected graph with edge weights, you want the shortest path from s to t, where the length of a path is the maximum edge on that path.  This can be solved in O(n+m) time by finding the median edge weight and (carefully) recursively deleting half the edges.

> Does anyone know a reference for
>   this?

Comment: Perhaps this is a moot point, but the problem you describe is the minimax path problem.  Bottleneck shortest path is the max-min version of what you describe.  An algorithm for one of the version generally (always?) yields an algorithm for the other version however.

Answer (score 10):

P. M. Camerini (1978), The min-max spanning tree problem and some extensions, *Information Processing Letters* **7** (1): 10–14, doi:[10.1016/0020-0190(78)90030-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2878%2990030-3)

Comment: Btw, if you want to solve the single-source (and in a sense the all-pairs) version of the problem for undirected graphs, you can do it in randomized O(m+n) time: T.C. Hu noted in 1961 that the bottleneck paths for all pairs are encoded in a max spanning tree; then Karger,Klein and Tarjan's linear time min spanning tree algorithm gives you what you want.

Comment: As far as I can tell the reference is not what I need.  An st path in a min-max spanning tree is not necessaryily a bottleneck shortest st path.  Also, the KKT linear expected time algorithm is not what I need either, since I want deterministic not expected running time.  Thanks anyway for the help though.

Comment: Actually, the st path P in a minimum spanning tree T has a minimum maximum edge weight over all st paths. Suppose it doesn't. Then let the max edge of P be e. Removing e from T creates a cut of the graph. The real minmax st path P' must have an edge e' crossing this cut. Adding e' to T\{e} creates a new spanning tree T' which must have a smaller cost than T since the weight of e' is at most the max edge weight on P' which is less than w(e). This contradicts the fact that T is a min spanning tree.

Answer (score 2):

[On the Bottleneck Shortest Path Problem](http://www.zib.de/Publications/Reports/ZR-06-22.pdf)

Comment: That one's mostly on the directed version of the problem and it's mostly superceded by an earlier 1988 paper of Gabow and Tarjan  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=955149 . See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem for many more references.

Comment: The link is broken.